# Android app having trouble accessing posts

Tags: support, bug, android-app

I'm using the Stack Exchange app v1. 0.95 <sup>1</sup> on a Samsung Galaxy S7 Edge running Android v8.0.0.

<sup>I'm aware that development on the app is frozen. The interface is cleaner and (usually) faster for me to work with than the mobile website.</sup>

Over this past week, I've been experiencing problems of severe delays/freezes when trying to load posts and post my own comments/answers. Especially on Stack Overflow, where I spend most of my time (but I use the app to access several other SE sites, too).

Sometimes loading/posting takes several seconds (5-10), but it does eventually succeed.

Sometimes loading/posting freezes, but I can press the Back or App Switcher button on the device to kind of "wake up" the app without actually switching away from it.

Sometimes the app just freezes completely and I have to swipe it away and restart it.

But these are temporary solutions. The problem always comes back after a few minutes, or reading/posting a few times.

This is a recently new problem. It wasn't happening before.

Anyone else noticing this lately?

Comment: Does it freeze after some time you are using it or it can start freezing right away? I am not using Android app extensively, mostly to quickly check latest changes and few posts and I haven't noticed any issues similar to yours. But I always use app for minute or two at the most.

Comment: @HerMajestyQueenofARC it is not immediately, but it can start freezing pretty quickly after starting the app. I wonder if this is a server side problem, and the app is just waiting on the server to respond. On the other hand, my phone is pretty low on available storage, I wonder if that is contributing to the issue, too. Hard to tell

Comment: @RemyLebeau If you're in the app and it "freezes" when viewing a post, can you press "back" to get to the previous menu, or is then whole app literally frozen?

Comment: @Carcigenicate sometimes the app can go back a screen, and sometimes the whole app is frozen

Comment: The former is almost definitely what I describe in the second point unless it does it from a fresh start. The latter might be caused by poor memory on your phone; although the app only uses like 250mb of memory on my phone. If you have a really low-memory phone, it might be a combination of the two.